# Why cant I import on R studio?

Tags: rstudio

I'm new to R. I tired importing dataset on R studio but the full page is not showing. I cant click on import. I tried installing other versions but its still not working.

[image]

Comment: So your problem is that you cannot *see* the Import button in order to press it? Just use `mydat <- read.csv("path/to/myfile.csv")` without the fancy GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Adetumi, try this hack to be able to move a window beyond the scope of the display boundary.

Notes:

1. The "Import Dataset" popup is still part of the RStudio IDE window, so the operation will move all of them together.
2. Because of #1, when we move it *up* in order to see the Import window, the upper-left corner of RStudio will become hidden, so knowing how many keys to press to initiate *Move* is important (the second time, you'll be doing it blind).
3. This is applicable to almost *any* windows application, not just RStudio.

Steps to move:

1. Press `Alt-Space`, you'll get a Windows Application Menu popup on the upper-left corner of the application.

   [image: window application-menu]
2. Either (but not both):

   1. Press `M` (for *Move*); or
   2. Go `Down` twice, notice that *Move* is now highlighted. Press `Enter`.

   [image]
3. In my windows, the mouse icon changes to a four-way icon, yours may be the same but almost certainly different from the normal arrow. At this point, use the four arrow keys to move the RStudio IDE and its Import Dataset window up until you can see the `Import` button.
4. When that is done, you will likely be unable to see the title bar of the application in order to move it (if mouse-moving is your normal thing). In this case, you can do the same thing, though this time you are doing it blind: one of `Alt-Space M` or `Alt-Space Down Down Enter`, then arrows to move the window.

I'm comfortable enough with keyboard shortcuts like this one, but there are other alternatives such as https://superuser.com/a/187442. (I often use `Alt-Space N` instead of M to minimize windows without the mouse. But then again, I'm very much a keyboard person, the mouse is rarely used while "working" on my code.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I will not respond directly to your question but I can help you import the data another way round.

Open Notepad, paste your data there, save it as a .csv file and the in R use read.csv() function. It takes as an argument a string with full path to the file.

Comment: What does opening in Notepad do here? If the only purpose is to rename it to CSV, then ... just rename it in File Explorer or on the command-line. (`read.csv` does not care about the file extension, it never checks ... it'll try reading it the same if the file is `mydata.csv` or `mydata`.)

Comment: @r2evans The point is that the author seems not to have a file with data, he just has this text he pasted into the window. Honestly, I don't know this window feature he's showing. If it's a file loader, then you are right, Notepad is not necessary.

Comment: There's nothing in that picture to suggest that there is text without a file. If you use RStudio (I don't, so I had to verify this behavior), click on *File > Import Dataset > From Text (base)*, find a CSV file, and notice that the *contents* of the CSV file are displayed in the modal window. The OP has yet to reply, but my guess is that this is a screen-resolution thing and has to do solely with the RStudio IDE and Windows (and nothing about the R language).